# Is it possible to hijack X server of a process?

Tags: linux, ssh, x-server

Is there a way to SSH to a machine and forward the X of already running process to my SSH client (as if I launched this process via SSH with X forwarding)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Not in a standard X server.
There are a pile of research projects out there that are trying to accomplish this, but none have produced code that has been incorporated into the x server project.

This is a duplicate question. see: ["Detach" and "Reattach" xterms across X sessions?](https://superuser.com/questions/1674/detach-and-reattach-xterms-across-x-sessions)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, it is not possible with the current X.org server (it would have to be something that is supported by the original X server on the remote machine). The problem is that the X server stores a lot of state and there is no way to transfer that state to the new server.

However, if it is possible to setup something like [Xpra](http://code.google.com/p/partiwm/wiki/xpra) on the remote machine ahead of time (e.g. set it up to run on login), then it is possible to redirect the clients later.