# After-the-fact remote nohup with tcsh

Tags: kill, tcsh, nohup

I have a tcsh instance in an xterm that is running a long-term (weeks?) process.  The Xvnc server it's running under went out in the weeds; it's consuming 100% CPU and is unresponsive.  (This is a known bug and I *know* that it's unrecoverable.)

The long-term process is currently blocking on stdout.

Is there any way I can kill an underlying process — the tcsh, the xterm, whatever — and keep that long-term process running?

(Please, no answers about `screen`.  I know.  It's not my process; it's a user's.  They won't learn.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[This post](http://dbaspot.com/forums/shell/369353-move-process-screen.html) may help.  The recommendation is:

1. background the process (with Ctrl-Z, then **bg**)
2. run **disown -h %[jobid]** (likely a bash-ism, so you'll have to translate for tcsh)

The **bad news**, of course, is that the **bg** would need to be done in the same shell the process is running in... but ... it might already be backgrounded.

The **really bad news** is that the **disown** call might need to be done in the same shell.  In which case, yes, you're screwed.  But I'm not sure, maybe root can force-disconnect it.

Hmm.  Possible [good news](http://www.plug.org/pipermail/plug/2004-August/006387.html) -- tcsh does the **disown** automatically:

> If tcsh exits abnormally, it disowns jobs running in the background 
>   automatically when it exits.

So, if your long-term process is already backgrounded, killing its tcsh parent should allow it to continue.  The process is now disconnected from the starting terminal.  (If not, see "bad news" above.)

Unfortunately, it's not screen, so there's no real reconnecting.  You can fake it with gdb maybe (again, from the first link):

> [...] with some dirty hacks, it is not
>   impossible to reopen a process'
>   stdout/stderr/stdin.
>
> So you could still create a blank
>   screen window (for instance that runs
>   sleep).
>
> And then use gdb for instance to
>   attach to the process, do some 
>   call close(0)
>   call close(1)
>   call close(2)
>   call open("/dev/pts/xx", ...)
>   call dup(0)
>   call dup(0)
>   detach
>
> The process' output would go to
>   screen. It wouldn't be attached to
>   that screen terminal, so for instance[sic]
>   would kill the "sleep" command, not
>   the process, but that could be enough
>   for the OP.

I wonder if there shouldn't be "call dup(1)" and "call dup(2)" in that process as well...

Comment: Yeah, it's a foreground process, so I guess I'm screwed.

Comment: Yeah.  but like you said, it's not your process, not your fault.  sorry you get stuck with the mess, tho.

Comment: This totally just saved my ass.  I encountered the same problem I posted about initially, which was that the process was blocking on STDOUT when the X server (and, I guess, the xterm in between) wedged.  It turns out I didn't really need to do anything except close STDOUT.  That output was irrelevant; the real data is in a log file somewhere.  So I was able to attach with gdb, run "call close(1)" and then "cont" and it's moving along again.  Thanks so much!

Comment: huh! interesting.  that unfroze everything?  weirdness.  glad it helped tho!

Comment: No, it should be dup(0).  The dup(0) calls take fd 0 and copy it over the next free descriptors, which happen to be 1 and 2, if you've closed them previously.  dup2(fd1, fd2) might be a more clear spelling, assuming you can remember which is the source and which is the destination (I never can remember that).

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that sending "Ctrl-Z" to a foreground process and sending SIGSTOP to its pid are the same thing.  (SIGCONT starts the process back again.)  I don't know if this would be helpful for others in the same situation or not, but, in my quick testing, sending SIGSTOP followed by SIGCONT duplicates "Ctrl-Z" followed by `bg`.

Comment: You can maybe re-attach via reptyr. See : http://serverfault.com/questions/466129/restore-ssh-session/466183#466183

Answer (score 3):

These questions refer to a program called Cryopid which may help you. I don't have any experience with it, however.

[Moving a process between hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192838/can-you-freeze-a-c-c-process-and-continue-it-on-a-different-host)

[Moving xterms between X sessions](https://superuser.com/questions/1674/detach-and-reattach-xterms-across-x-sessions/8513#8513)

[Nohup and screen a process](https://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process)

Comment: CryoPID sounds really neat, but I had a family of processes, and it doesn't support freezing and resuming multiple processes, at least not yet.