# How to access Stdout / Stderr of a detached process?

Tags: unix, process

I'm having a php-cli script that is running (detached) in the background.

Is there a way to attach to it's Stdout/Stderr in order to see the output of the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably do this with `gdb`.  I [wrote about the process](https://superuser.com/questions/50058/after-the-fact-remote-nohup-with-tcsh/50077#50077) in an answer to a vaguely-related question.

Answer (score 3):

I like using strace it's abit less intimidating than GDB.

```
strace -s 100000 -e write=1  -e trace=write -p $PID 2>&1 | \
   sed 's/^write(1, //;t;d'
```

Answer (score 1):

[dupx](http://www.isi.edu/~yuri/dupx/dupx_man.html) is the complete solution which implements what @quack is refering to:

> Dupx is a simple utility to remap files of an already running program. Shells like Bash allow easy input/output/error redirection at the time the program is started using >,  /tmp/stdout 
> will redirect output of echo to /tmp/stdout.
> Standard shells however do not provide the capability of remapping (redirecting) of output (or input, or error) for an already started process. Dupx tries to address this problem by using dup(2) system call from inside gdb(1). Dupx is currently implemented as a simple shell wrapper around a gdb script.

Comment: the motivation to reanswer this question came from http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2110636 and https://gist.github.com/782263 and no good results while searching superuser. i found the vaguely-related posts on SU but things could be simpler.