# If I log out of a linux ssh shell, is there any way to jump back into a process that was running?

Tags: linux, login, process, logout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux process to background - relogin - how to bring process back to foreground?](https://superuser.com/questions/106540/linux-process-to-background-relogin-how-to-bring-process-back-to-foreground)

Okay, kind of a weird question but let's say I'm running a long-running batch script in a terminal window and I close that terminal window.

Is it possible, in any way, to ssh back into that server and run a command that pops you back into that process, so you can see it running again?

This is on linux (Redhat).

Thanks

Comment: this has been asked before... probable duplicates: http://superuser.com/questions/106540/linux-process-to-background-relogin-how-to-bring-process-back-to-foreground .. http://superuser.com/questions/111631/leave-bash-script-running-on-remote-terminal-while-not-logged-in .. http://superuser.com/questions/127349/continue-process-after-closing-terminal-closed .. http://superuser.com/questions/28568/screen-a-running-process ..

Comment: Wasn't a background process but hopefully one of the other answers applies.

Answer (score 0):

you'd want to run the process in screen, most likely, then detach the screen session.

I also think you can switch a process to the background with an && at the end of the line invoking it, and using fg *n* where n is the process number to bring it back to the front, though i haven't tried this yet.